# JUnit with H2 database - Does h2 memory will be replicated for each testcase

Tags: spring-boot, junit, h2

Hie, I have decent amounted of knowledge on how Junit works. Like for maintaining isolation between tests it copies all memory to that testcase and executes test on that copied data.

Does this same happen when we init huge memory objects like H2 Data base??

If that's case the only way of not hitting GC error is restricting parallel thread count?

Comment: Are you talking about spring boot test or plain junit test?

Comment: Actually In Both

Comment: Spring has `@DirtiesContext`. So in my opinion, If the context is not reused across tests, there wouldn't be even need for `@DirtiesContext`, so that means it creates the database once and reuses and when you don't want that behaviour, you customise it `@DirtiesContext`. For your plain junit test that does not run using spring, it depnds on how you create the database